# How to output multi-dimensional arrays alongside single-dimension arrays in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I would like to output the following code in the console so that the result reads:

My hobbies on Mondays are Poker, VideoGames

My hobbies on Tuesday are Board Games, Hiking, Rockclimbing

My hobbies on Wednesdays are Driving, Shopping

I know this is fairly basic stuff, but for some reason none of the help I've found online has solved this for me (definitely me just misreading or misunderstanding things).

I'm using nested for loops, which I think is correct, but for some reason I can't get past the first array in the multi-dimensional hobbies array. The weekdays output as I need them to, but for each weekday I want to output the entirety of the first, second and third array in the variable hobbies for Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday respectively. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
var hobbies = ['Poker','VideoGames'];

              ['Board Games', 'Hiking', 'Rockclimbing'];

              ['Driving', 'Shopping'];

const weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"];

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
console.log("My hobbies on", weekdays[i], "are ");
for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
  console.log(hobbies[?]);
}
```

Comment: I think the way u create multi-dimensional hobbies array is wrong.
It should be like
```var hobbies = [['Poker','VideoGames'],
               ['Board Games', 'Hiking', 'Rockclimbing'],
               ['Driving', 'Shopping']];
```


Then u can access hobbies[index]

Answer (score 2):

This is the code you are looking for:

```
var hobbies = [['Poker','VideoGames'],
               ['Board Games', 'Hiking', 'Rockclimbing'],
               ['Driving', 'Shopping']];

const weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"];

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log("My hobbies on" + weekdays[i] + "are " + hobbies[i].join(', '));
}
```

Comment: It would be worth pointing out that you had to modify the hobbies variable as it was not a multidimensional array.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to tell him that it was not well defined

Comment: Thanks a lot - I am a doofus for missing the pair of square brackets and that makes a lot of sense. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

So basically you've to iterate over the arrays and get the result.

```js
var hobbies = [
  ['Poker', 'VideoGames'],

  ['Board Games', 'Hiking', 'Rockclimbing'],

  ['Driving', 'Shopping']
];

const weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"];

for (i = 0; i < hobbies.length; i++) {
  console.log("My hobbies on", weekdays[i], "are "+ hobbies[i].join() );
}
```

updated code for error handling.

```js
function getWeekdayname(index){
    const weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"];
    if(index < weekdays.length){
      return weekdays[i];
    }
    
    return 'X';

}

var hobbies = [
      ['Poker', 'VideoGames'],

      ['Board Games', 'Hiking', 'Rockclimbing'],

      ['Driving', 'Shopping'],
      ['Drivin 3g', 'Shoppin 6g']
    ];


    for (i = 0; i < hobbies.length; i++) {
      console.log("My hobbies on", getWeekdayname(i), "are "+ hobbies[i].join() );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for responding, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can make it in many ways , I advice you to watch a js course or any data structure course first

I can write it in many ways but i preferred to edit your own code since you understand this way better.

```
var hobbies_ = [
    ['Poker','VideoGames'],
    ['Board Games', 'Hiking', 'Rockclimbing'],
    ['Driving', 'Shopping']
];

var weekdays_ = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"];


for (i = 0; i < weekdays_.length; i++) {
    let day_hobbies ='';
    for (x = 0; x < hobbies_[i].length ; x++)
    {
        if(i == 0){
            day_hobbies += `${ hobbies_[x] }`;
            }else{
            day_hobbies += `, ${ hobbies_[x] }`;
        }

    }
    console.log("My hobbies on", weekdays_[i], "are ",day_hobbies);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for responding, much appreciated - I'll check it out